# Extensible .NET Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I would like to distribute a DLL with a `ConfigurationSection` as follows:

```
public class StandardConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    public static StandardConfiguration GetInstance()
    {
        return (StandardConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customConfigSection");
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("childConfig")]
    public StandardChildConfig ChildConfig
    {
        get { return (StandardChildConfig)this["childConfig"]; }
        set { this["childConfig"] = value; }
    }
}

public class StandardChildConfig : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("p1")]
    public string P1
    {
        get { return (string)this["p1"]; }
        set { this["p1"] = value; }
    }
}
```

I would like to make the `ConfigurationSection` and its child `ConfigElement` inheritable.  This can be done using a type parameter as follows:

```
public class StandardConfiguration<TChildConfig> : ConfigurationSection
    where TChildConfig : StandardChildConfig
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("childConfig")]
    public TChildConfig ChildConfig
    {
        get { return (TChildConfig)this["childConfig"]; }
        set { this["childConfig"] = value; }
    }
}

public class StandardChildConfig : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("p1")]
    public string P1
    {
        get { return (string)this["p1"]; }
        set { this["p1"] = value; }
    }
}
```

However, I think this would prevent me from having a static `Instance` to reference from other classes in my DLL because I would not know the ultimate type of child `ConfigurationElement`.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to implement this more cleanly are welcome.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Assuming that there is a `<customConfigSection>` in the application's configuration, I can use `StandardConfiguration.GetInstance().ChildConfig.P1` to access the `P1` value in the first scenario.  How would I access that same value in the second scenario?  How would I implement `GetInstance()`?

**EDIT 2**

Below is the "zero-coding" scenario:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section
            name="customConfig"
            type="WebsiteTemplate.Config.StandardConfigruation, WebsiteTemplate"
        />
    </configSections>
    <customConfig baseProp1="a">
        <childConfig baseProp2="b" />
    </customConfig>
</configuration>
```

And here is the scenario where the configuration was extended:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section
            name="customConfig"
            type="WebsiteTemplate.Extended.Config.ExtendedConfigruation, WebsiteTemplate.Extended"
        />
    </configSections>
    <customConfig baseProp1="a" extendedProp1="c">
        <childConfig baseProp2="b" extendedProp2="d" />
    </customConfig>
</configuration>
```

Comment: And the type of the `Instance` can't be `ConfigurationElement`?  I'm unclear what you're asking...

Comment: @Peter Ritchie - I have added an example of what I am trying to do.  Let me know if this makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: just use my library for this https://github.com/aloneguid/config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "answer" to my question is to break the base config up into an abstract class with type parameters and an interface.

Below shows what is defined in the BaseLib.dll.  There is a default configuration and default child configuration.

**Interface and absract class**

```
public interface IAppConfig
{
    string AppProp1 { get; }
    SubConfig SubConfig { get; }
}

public abstract class BaseAppConfig<TSubConfig> : ConfigurationSection, IAppConfig
    where TSubConfig : SubConfig
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("appProp1")]
    public string AppProp1
    {
        get { return (string)this["appProp1"]; }
        set { this["appProp1"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("subConfig")]
    public TSubConfig SubConfig
    {
        get { return (TSubConfig)this["subConfig"]; }
        set { this["subConfig"] = value; }
    }

    // Implement the interface
    string IAppConfig.AppProp1 { get { return this.AppProp1; } }
    SubConfig IAppConfig.SubConfig { get { return this.SubConfig; } }
}
```

**Default implementations**

```
public class AppConfig : BaseAppConfig<SubConfig>
{
    const string SECTION_KEY = "AppConfig";

    public static IAppConfig Instance
    {
        get { return (IAppConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(SECTION_KEY); }
    }
}

public class SubConfig : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("supProp1")]
    public string SubProp1
    {
        get { return (string)this["supProp1"]; }
        set { this["supProp1"] = value; }
    }
}
```

**How the config is accessed from BaseLib.dll**

```
public class ArbitraryClass
{
    void DoSometing()
    {
        Console.Write(AppConfig.Instance.SubConfig.SubProp1);
    }
}
```

Below shows what is defined in the ExtLib.dll.  Both the configuration and child configuration are extended.

**Extended implementations**

```
public class ExtAppConfig : BaseAppConfig<ExtSubConfig>
{
    public static ExtAppConfig Instance
    {
        get { return (ExtAppConfig)AppConfig.Instance; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("extAppProp1")]
    public string ExtAppProp1
    {
        get { return (string)this["extAppProp1"]; }
        set { this["extAppProp1"] = value; }
    }
}

public class ExtSubConfig : SubConfig
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("extSubProp1")]
    public string ExtSubProp1
    {
        get { return (string)this["extSubProp1"]; }
        set { this["extSubProp1"] = value; }
    }
}
```

**How the config is accessed from ExtLib.dll**

```
public class ExtArbitraryClass
{
    void DoSometing()
    {
        Console.Write(ExtAppConfig.Instance.SubConfig.ExtSubProp1);
    }
}
```

There is a little more defined in the library, but it should make extending this configuration relatively easy.

Answer (score 2):

In the second instance `StandardConfiguration.GetInstance()` doesn't make any sense because `StandardConfiguraiton` is generic.  You'd have to use `StandardConfiguration<MyChildConfig>.GetInstance().ChildConfig.P1`

You might be able to do something like this:

```
public class StandardConfigurationBase : ConfigurationSection
{
    public static StandardConfigurationBase GetInstance()
    {
        return (StandardConfigurationBase) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customConfigSection");
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("childConfig")]
    public StandardChildConfig ChildConfig
    {
        get { return (StandardChildConfig) this["childConfig"]; }
        set { this["childConfig"] = value; }
    }
}

public class StandardConfiguration<TChildConfig> : StandardConfigurationBase
where TChildConfig : StandardChildConfig
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("childConfig")]
    public new TChildConfig ChildConfig
    {
        get { return (TChildConfig)this["childConfig"]; }
        set { this["childConfig"] = value; }
    }
}
public class StandardChildConfig : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("p1")]
    public string P1
    {
        get { return (string)this["p1"]; }
        set { this["p1"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Then access the child when its specific type is not known:

```
    StandardConfigurationBase b = new StandardConfiguration<StandardChildConfig>();
    StandardChildConfig x = StandardConfigurationBase.GetInstance().ChildConfig;
```

But, I'm unclear of the real value in doing this.

Comment: I am creating a web-site template for distribution in my company.  The template will come with a DLL and that expects a base configuration.  I would like implementers of this template to be able to extend the configuration.  It is straightforward to add properties to the base configuration.  What is tricky is how to allow `ConfigurationElement`s of the `ConfigurationSection` to be extendable.  I understand each website could create its own configuration, but I was thinking that doing things my way would keep the configuration cleaner.  I may have been wrong though :)